# How to link a class with another class thru a relationship table

Tags: java

I am a complete beginner and trying to write a code where the requirement is that when an account holder approaches the bank counter and provides his account number; upon entry of account number, the system pulls out its name & address. I understand that a relationship table will need to be maintained with account number & name, address etc., but how to write a code where upon entry of account number, it pulls out the details as maintained in relationship table?

Comment: Do you only want to use Java and store everything in memory?

Answer (score 2):

My answer assumes you don't need to store these account holder entries once you shut down the program. (The bank will be "blank" everytime the program starts)

---

A simple way that I would approach this problem is seeing what objects I would need to make.

Well here's what I do know: Banks are smart, they will only assign one account number per bank account! Now we're on to something.

And what else does a bank account have? Well it would contain your name, address, and all your information like you said.

So now we already have:

```
public class BankAccount {
    int accountNumber;
    int nameOnAccount;
    // And so on and so on. We also need all the methods associated with this class.
```

But I need to store a bunch of these, so why not make an `ArrayList` of `BankAccount`?

Then, when someone comes with their bank account number, I can check that arrayList to see if that `bankAccount` exists and if not, it can make a new entry for the new customer!

I think that should be enough to get you started.

EDIT:

To answer the second part, you would want something like:

```
private BankAccount getDetails(int accountNumber) {
    for (BankAcount bankAccount : lstofBankAccounts) {
        if (bankAccount.getAccountNumber() == accountNumber)
            return bankAccount;
    }
    // Do something if there is no account associated with that account number
}
```

Comment: You write a comment, asking a question and post an answer before Arun Kushwaha answers your question? Instead of "assuming" something, it would be better to wait until Arun Kushwaha answers your question.

Comment: I figured the logic I was addressing in my question would apply no matter if they wanted to have persistent storage or not.

If they do want persistent storage that's another part that needs to be addressed.

But I figured the first step is just getting it working in a basic example.

Comment: The first step is understanding what OP is asking about.

Comment: @Turing85 He answered everything he could without more context. If the OP responds saying he wants the accounts written to disk, Marcin can add that to his answer. I don't see what the issue is. 'Edit' is a wonderful feature that allows answers to grow.

Comment: @BoDidely and comments are a wonderful thing to ask questions about OP. If the question is unclear, it gets closed. [Writing speculative answers is not how SO works](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266426/is-it-ok-to-answer-vague-unclear-questions).

Comment: Maybe using "assumes" was the wrong word.

Whether or not data is stored anywhere, the above steps still need to be taken to create a BankAccount object and so on.